# Pasting a new row into the next blank row using VBA is not expanding table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy-paste

I have the below code to paste a new row into a table in a new worksheet in SharePoint.

When pasting into the next blank row the table is not changing dynamically with it.

```vb
Sub Complete()
    
    Dim tb1 As ListObject, tb2 As ListObject, tbl As ListObject
    Dim Lrow As Long, dRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim searchRange As Range, foundCell As Range
    Dim mysearch As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, Scwb As Workbook
    Dim ScRow As Range
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    mysearch = Sheets("OI").Range("D4").Value
    
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("OI")
    Set tb1 = ws.ListObjects("OITs")
    Set tb2 = wb.Sheets("TDets").ListObjects("OIFinal")
    Lrow = tb2.ListRows.Count
    
    With ws
        .Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With
    
    tb1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<>" & vbNullString
    NumRows = tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
    tb1.DataBodyRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    tb2.DataBodyRange(Lrow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    tb1.DataBodyRange.Columns(4).Resize(, 7).ClearContents
    tb1.Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=" & vbNullString
    
    With ws
        .Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
    
    With wb.Sheets("CReqs")
        Set searchRange = .Range("G1", .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Set Scwb = Workbooks.Open("https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/*****/Shared%20Documents/General/NAA/Apps.xlsx")
    Set tbl = Scwb.Sheets("AppAccs").ListObjects("Pending")
    dRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
    
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Yes"
        foundCell.Offset(0, -6).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=tbl.Range(dRow, "A").Offset(1) ' This is the line that pastes the code to a new wb but does not expand the table.
        Scwb.Save
        Scwb.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "We cannot find the ID " & mysearch & " to send for approval. Please check ID."
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have resolved the above by simply adding tbl.Resize tbl.Range.CurrentRegion to the next line after pasting across to the new SP workbook.

Comment: there is also a method `listrows.add` which returns the empty new row.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the above by simply adding tbl.Resize tbl.Range.CurrentRegion to the next line after pasting across to the new SP workbook